# How to get link to composition by using status callbacks twilio

Tags: twilio

Here is what I tried but it's not working.

This guy is responsible for creating a composition after the meeting is ended.

```
app.post('/api/endMeeting', (req, res) => {
  const roomSid = req.body.roomSid;
  userEmail = req.body.userEmail;
  const client = require('twilio')(config.twilio.apiKey, config.twilio.apiSecret, {accountSid: config.twilio.accountSid});
  client.video.rooms(roomSid).update({ status: 'completed' });
  client.video.compositions.create({
    roomSid: roomSid,
    audioSources: '*',
    videoLayout: {
      grid : {
        video_sources: ['*']
      }
    },
    statusCallback: `${process.env.REACT_APP_BASE_URL}/api/getMeeting`,
    statusCallbackMethod: 'POST',
    format: 'mp4'
  }).then(() => {
    // sendRecordingEmail(composition.sid, userEmail);
    res.status(200).send({
      message: 'success'
    });
  }).catch(err => {
    res.status(500).send({
      message: err.message
    });
  });
});
```

And this guy will send the download link of the composition to the participant when it's available.

```
app.post('/api/getMeeting', (req, res) => {
  if (req.query.StatusCallbackEvent === 'composition-available') {
    const client = require('twilio')(config.twilio.apiKey, config.twilio.apiSecret, {accountSid: config.twilio.accountSid});
    const compositionSid = req.query.CompositionSid;
    const uri = "https://video.twilio.com/v1/Compositions/" + compositionSid + "/Media?Ttl=3600";

    client.request({
      method: "GET",
      uri: uri,
    }).then((response) => {
      const requestUrl = request(response.data.redirect_to);
      sendRecordingEmail(requestUrl, userEmail);
      res.status(200).send("success");

    }).catch((error) => {
      res.status(500).send("Error fetching /Media resource " + error);
    });
  }
});
```

I can confirm that the composition is created exactly in the Twilio console.
But it seems the status callback guy is not working and I can see the below issue.

[image: Bug from Twilio debugger]

It seems I made mistakes in using the status callback.
Please let me know what is the problem and how I can solve this.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you very much for `@philnash`'s help in solving this problem.

---

I solved the above issue and I can get the download link of the composition for now.

The problem was in the status callback function and I should use `req.body` instead of `req.query` because of the status callback method. (It's `POST` on my code.)

Here is the code that is fixed.

```
app.post('/api/getMeeting', (req, res) => {
  if (req.body.StatusCallbackEvent === 'composition-available') {
    const client = require('twilio')(config.twilio.apiKey, config.twilio.apiSecret, {accountSid: config.twilio.accountSid});
    const compositionSid = req.body.CompositionSid;
    const uri = "https://video.twilio.com/v1/Compositions/" + compositionSid + "/Media?Ttl=3600";

    client.request({
      method: "GET",
      uri: uri,
    }).then((response) => {
      const requestUrl = response.body.redirect_to; // Getting the redirect link that user can download composition
      sendRecordingEmail(requestUrl, userEmail); // Send URL via email to the user
      res.status(200).send("success");

    }).catch((error) => {
      res.status(500).send("Error fetching /Media resource " + error);
    });
  } else {
    res.status(204).send('compositioin is not available');
  }
});
```

Comment: does this /api/getMeeting url get called automatically by twilio or we need to do anything else to get status callback?

Comment: Please check the other code attachment above. `/api/endMeeting`
As you can see, I just passed this StatusCallback in creating the composition API.
So `/api/getMeeting` will be called automatically by Twilio.